# React Labels not displaying in browser

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am new to React and especially formik. I am trying to learn how to create a login form using formik that will display a label called email with the email input. A label called password with the password input and a button called submit.

My problem is that only the two inputs and submit button displays in the browser. The two labels for email and password do not display in the browser. Please advise how I can fix this.

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import FormikContainer from './components/FormikContainer';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <LoginForm />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

LoginForm.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import FormikContainer from './FormikContainer';
import FormikControl from './FormikControl';
function LoginForm() {
  const initialValues = {
    email: '',
    password: ''
  };

  const validationschema = Yup.object({
    email: Yup.string().email('invalid email format').required('Requird'),
    password: Yup.string().required('Required')
  });

  const onSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log('Form data', values);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationschema={validationschema}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
      >
        {(formik) => {
          return (
            <Form>
              <FormikControl
                control="input"
                type="email"
                label="Email"
                name="email"
              />

              <FormikControl
                control="input"
                type="password"
                label="Password"
                name="password"
              />
              <button type="submit" disabled={!formik.isValid}>
                Submit
              </button>
            </Form>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}

export default LoginForm;
```

FormikControl.js:

```
import React from 'react';

function FormikControl(props) {
  const { control, ...rest } = props;
  switch (control) {
    case 'input':
      return <input {...rest} />;
    case 'textarea':
    case 'select':
    case 'radio':
    case 'checkbox':
    case 'date':
    default:
      return null;
  }
  return <div></div>;
}

export default FormikControl;
```

FormikContainer.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import FormikControl from './FormikControl';

function FormikContainer() {

      const initialValues = {
        email: ''
      };
      const validationschema = Yup.object({
        email: Yup.string().required('Required')
      });
      const onSubmit = (values) => console.log('Form data', values);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <Formik
            initialValues={initialValues}
            validationschema={validationschema}
            onSubmit={onSubmit}
          >
            {(formik) => (
              <Form>
                <FormikControl
                  control="input"
                  type="email"
                  label="Email"
                  name="email"
                />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
              </Form>
            )}
          </Formik>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default FormikContainer;
```

Comment: You are passing `label` as a prop to your `input` element in `FormikControl` but `input` doesn't have a `lable` attribute. You should add another `label` element

Comment: Hi thank you for your help. I tried adding a case 'label': in FormikControl but the labels still do not display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to do easily this instead :

```
function FormikControl({ control, id, label, ...rest }) {

  return (
  <>
   {control === "input" && <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>}
   <input id={id} {...rest} />
  </>
  );
}

export default FormikControl;
```

Comment: Thanks everything displays now. Even though everything displays in the browser, I get the following message in the console: Warning: Invalid DOM property `for`. Did you mean `htmlFor`?
    at label
    at FormikControl (http://localhost:3000/main.e595a5b641eafd19aded.hot-update.js:27:5)
    at form
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:4372:22
    at Formik (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:4040:19)
    at div
    at LoginForm
    at div
    at App

Comment: no problem Lizzy
if there is still something i can help then we can do some pair coding :)

Comment: Hi Shadi. The code works but I am getting the following error in my console: Even though everything displays in the browser, I get the following message in the console: Warning: Invalid DOM property for. Did you mean htmlFor? at label at FormikControl (localhost:3000/main.e595a5b641eafd19aded.hot-update.js:27:5) at form at localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:4372:22 at Formik (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:4040:19) at div at LoginForm at div at App

Comment: Just replace `for` with `htmlFor`

Comment: it was my bad when i forgot to do it , anyway i updated the answer above with `htmlFor` instead of `for` in <label> tag